# Can i Use Vimeo Video streaming for Android Native video view instead of Webview?

Tags: android, video-streaming, vimeo, vimeo-android

I need to use a video streaming service provider for my application in web as well as Android Platform. So i have some questions regarding the video playback. Please help me to solve it.

1 . Is Vimeo video streaming compatible for android native video view instead of Webview? I need to support devices having OS version 4.0+.

2 . Vimeo will manage the quality of video corresponding to the network bandwidth? Such as if the network is very slow whether it will automatically switch to the less quality video without interrupting the playback.

3 . If Vimeo can't provide these features. Suggest any service providers for my Video  streaming.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try it : https://github.com/ct7ct7ct7/Android-VimeoPlayer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PRO users on Vimeo.com have access to the HLS links of their own videos. You can find these under the "files" key when requesting your own videos (such as /me/videos, or /videos/{video_id})